# VS 2022 c++ app - Is it possible to make modifications to an .rc file at Build time?

Tags: c++, resources

I have a VS 2022 c++ project with a resource file.  I'd like to be able to modify the .rc when the project is built, preferably with command line parameters.  I'm not sure if this is possible and if so, how to go about it.

Comment: Your .rc file can include headers with constants. From my knowledge there are limitations on what the header may contain as the resource parser does not fully understand c++. Can you clarify what data you would like to add?

Comment: The resource compiler also as a `/D` command-line switch that you can use to define tokens, just like the C and C++ compilers. But, as said in the earlier comment, we need more details, here.

Comment: Yes, you can use macros just like in C++

Comment: Please give an example of what information you are trying to put in the .rc file at build time.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an exe to modify the rc file as per your requirements.
2. Configure Pre-Build event to call the exe. Use macros to specify the input files.

refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/specifying-build-events?view=msvc-170